# How to change Visual Studio 2015 install directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am unable to change the installation path for Visual Studio 2015 Professional.!

[image]

Is there a way to change the installation path?

Answer (score 1):

If a previous installation has already installed bits of Visual Studio, then the installation location cannot be changed. Bits of Visual Studio may have been installed as part of SQL Server Development Tools, Office and other products that ship with the Visual Studio Shell for example.

Once part of Visual Studio has been installed to the default Program Files directory, there is no way to change it, except by completely uninstalling all products that may have included parts of Visual Studio. I tend to find it's easier to just pave the machine and start afresh.